# Where can i report issues for the linked in api

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn changed after microsoft took over, they upgraded to v2 on their api and have a decent documentation about it.

But i am unable to find how to report issues to them? Does anybody know if there is a issue tracker on their side?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found it, they are using zendesk: https://linkedin.zendesk.com